# Preprogrammed  IC

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly

I'm curious about the PCB manufacturing, How are they manage the IC preprogramming? 
For example
I had designed a PCB, I sent to the manufacturer company, do they preprogramming my microcontroller if I provide the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some PCB assembly companies can do device programming for you. Otherwise, you will have to program the chips yourself, or buy them ready-programmed from your distributor or the manufacturer, and supply them to the assembly company. Microchip provides a programming service at quite low prices:

https://www.microchipdirect.com/programming/default.aspx

Another option is to get the boards assembled, and program the devices in-circuit yourself. You will also be able to test the boards before shipping them, which is an advantage.

Answer (score 5):

Your PCB shop won't always, but your microcontroller supplier should be able to do so. Most distributors like EBV, Avnet have a flexible programming service, which also allows programming unique IDs in the device, and a choice of markings (polyimide or Kapton sticker, lasering). My guess is that the PCB shop uses the same distributor's service, so it may be cheaper to go there directly.
You usually get a few samples to check if the programming is correct before the full batch is delivered. Especially when you need a unique ID programmed you'll have to check both samples to see that the IDs are effectively different. It happened to me once that they had forgotten to increment the counter.

---

For one product (50k/year) we thought we might save on the programming cost by doing it ourselves, on the PCB assy. A panel consisted of 24 PCBs and the idea was to place a panel on a testbed, and program the 24 devices simultaneously (to speed things up) through a PC with 24 serial ports. Canceled when we calculated we could never match the distri's price.
Nevertheless, whenever possible I always provide testpads for in-circuit programming at the bottom of my PCB, either for programming through serial port or JTAG. At 2mm they don't take that much space.

Answer (score 3):

Your PCB supplier has a number of options to download program code to an IC.

1. They could buy it pre-programmed from their IC supplier.
2. They could use an in circuit programmer if you designed one into the board.
3. They could program the IC prior to installing it on the board.

To program the IC prior to mounting it on the board the IC will need to be a package for which they make a programming device. Programmers for DIP packages are common. QFP IC programmers are rarer, but I've seen some where you can place the IC in a clam-shell type enclosure and program the IC. Remove the programmed IC then mount it on the PCB.

Answer (score -2):

If you're using PICs, Microchip has a low-cost programming service so you can buy parts ready-programmed.

Comment: Yes, Leon in his answer linked to it :-)